# PHP Regex match string but exclude a certain word

Tags: php, ajax, regex, api

This question has been asked multiple times, but I didn't find a working solution for my needs.

I've created a function to check for the URLs on the output of the Google Ajax API:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site%3Awww.bierdopje.com%2Fusers%2F+%22Gebruikersprofiel+van+%22+Stevo

I want to exclude the word "profile" from the output. So that if the string contains that word, skip the whole string.

This is the function I've created so far:

```
function getUrls($data)
{
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/www.bierdopje.com[^\" ]+/i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}

$urls = getUrls($data);
$filteredurls = array_unique($urls);
```

I've created a sample to make clear what I mean exactly:
http://rubular.com/r/1U9YfxdQoU

In the sample you can see 4 strings selected from which I only need the upper 2 strings.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you making your life hell by parsing JSON with a regular expression?

Comment: Your code is fine. What issue you facing in that ?

Comment: @Rikesh, the problem is that it has 4 matches instead of 2 and I don't know how I'd "unmatch" the last 2 matches. Check my sample to see what I mean.

Comment: Check [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hXepaz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getUrls($data)
{
    $regex = '@"(https?://www\\.bierdopje\\.com[^"]*+(?<!/profile))"@';
    return preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches) ?
        array_unique($matches[1]) : array();
}

$urls = getUrls($data);
```

Result: http://ideone.com/dblvpA

vs `json_decode`: http://ideone.com/O8ZixJ

But **generally** you should use `json_decode`.

Comment: Not just 'generally', the regex solution will just break painfully when something is changed in the Google output, a URL is added or removed, or the sample output includes a URL.

Comment: Thanks! The code worked just fine for me. I also want to thank Niels for providing the code on how to use json_decode properly. That comes handy too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions to parse JSON data. What you want to do is parse the JSON and loop over it to find the correct matching elements.

Sample code:

```
$input = file_get_contents('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site%3Awww.bierdopje.com%2Fusers%2F+%22Gebruikersprofiel+van+%22+Stevo');
$parsed = json_decode($input);

$cnt = 0;
foreach($parsed->responseData->results as $response)
{
   // Skip strings with 'profile' in there
   if(strpos($response->url, 'profile') !== false)
       continue;

   echo "Result ".++$cnt."\n\n";
   echo 'URL: '.$response->url."\n";
   echo 'Shown: '.$response->visibleUrl."\n";
   echo 'Cache: '.$response->cacheUrl."\n\n\n";
}
```

<kbd>[**Sample on CodePad**](http://codepad.org/UidhOOiY)</kbd> (since it doesn't support loading external files the string is inlined there)

Comment: Thank you for the code. That will come handy. I can't +1 you, but once I receive the right amount of rep. I will do that later (if possible).